# Exception calling ExecuteNonQuery in PowerShell to Azure PaaS database

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm having an odd issue using the System.Data.SqlClient in PowerShell. The following works, using MSSMS:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[secDb_AADDevices]
       ([objectGuid]
       ,[displayName]
       ,[deviceGuid])
 VALUES
       ('test','here','now')
```

But when doing this in PowerShell:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO secDb_AADDevices ('objectGuid','displayName','deviceGuid') VALUES('test','here','now')"
$sqlCmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sqlQuery, $sqlConn)
$sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It fails;

```
Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid column name 'objectGuid'.
Invalid column name 'displayName'.
Invalid column name 'deviceGuid'."
At line:4 char:1
+ $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException
```

The column types in MSSQL are nvarchar(50) not null.

I've simplified it as much as possible to reduce complexity while debugging, will parameterize when this part works.

I've triple-verified that MSSQL and PowerShell ($sqlConn object) are connected to the same server and database instance, using the exact same user.

Comment: You don't and shouldn't delimit your column names with single quote characters.

Comment: Your `INSERT` statement should be identical to the one you successfully executed in SSMS.

Comment: @SMor thanks! Removing the single quotes fixed it :)